# Convert a big .osm file to .map

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, offline

I have a 3.3GB .osm file and I'm trying to convert it to .map with Osmosis with the following

```
osmosis --read-xml mexico.osm --mapfile-writer file=mexico.map
```

but I get the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, I guess because of the file size.

Is there another way to convert it?

Comment: Maybe you should look at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis/Tuning#Memory

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar once. Load your osm file to some gis software, edit it (keep only what you really need) and then save it as csv. I thing you are talking about mapserver when you refer to a map file, if so, just call your csv from the DATA tag.

Comment: As per the [Tour] please do not include chit chat like Hope That Helps in your posts.

Comment: .map file is different from mapserver map file. this one is used in android.

Answer (score 0):

.osm is an xml based format which has very big size. You should convert it to binary .pbf format to reduce the size and then convert it to .map. Since binary process faster the 2 step process should be faster than direct conversion